# how to test controller without a view in rspec?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Rspec and adding unit test cases to my project. when testing a controller (sample below) , how to test the methods in controller. when controller returns data from another service , do we need to add test cases for that service as well?

```
Module Api
 class QuoteController

    def index
       Lib::Service::QuoteSearch() //returns json array of 
    end

    def show
    end

 end
end
```

service class

```
Module Lib
 class Service
  include HTTParty 
  base_uri "https://www.quotescomare.com"

  class << self
    def filter_json(response)
      //sort highest price to lowest
    end

    def QuoteSearch
     begin 
       response = HTTParty.get(url)
       if response.successful?
         filter_json(response)
       else
         raise 'invalid response'
       end
     end
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you also add ```Lib::Service::QuoteSearch()``` to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can add two test cases for it like you propose in question. One for `QuoteController` is it calling and serving returns json array of, secondly another test case for `Lib::Service::QuoteSearch()` in order to check correctness of result. One for `QuoteController` can be.

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe QuoteController do
  describe 'GET index' do
    it '[fill here for your case]' do
      ...
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      ...
    end
  end
```

Comment: thanks for very helpful comments. I have added service class to this question. I have couple of follow up question - so for the QuoteController, are we simply testing that we can make a call to the controller method and get a status code 200? or we need add more to it. secondly, for the service class,, what all do i need to test. what would be your approach?

Comment: For first question yes. ```QuoteController``` calls another module and we don't know what is happening in ```QuoteSearch```. We can only test success and fail(with a stub) in ```QuoteController```.  On the other hand at ```QuoteSearch``` side you can use this kind of gem(https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to record your response to casette and use it in your test to create a fake api call and getting a successful response. Same for error response. Basically 4 tests can cover all code

Comment: great thanks. I will look into that gem. sorry for the redundant question. I am new to rails development. test cases for the service class, do I directly make calls to the external api ( or fake one) or do I create an instance of service class , in my case do service.QuoteSearch() . or just use httparty to directly make calls?

Comment: Real calls on tests are not recommended, use vcr instead to make one real call to api, record it to casette and then use that for your tests. With that way if api is down your tests will be safe anyway